# Show category name in the post URL only for specific categories

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

Is there a way to show the category name in the URL of a post which is in a specific category? I.e:

I have a site which have a blog and two categories, blog and resources; right now this blog have the setting of only show the post name in the url (blabla.com/postname) so, all post follow this rule. But now, I have to enable a way for the resources posts show the category name (resources) in the URL, something like this: blabla.com/resources/postname, and having this two settings living side by side.

Blog must remain blog.com/postname,
Resources should be blog.com/resources/postname

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create a custom post type with an archive.

```
<?php
register_post_type('resource',
    array(
        // Enable Core Categories and Tags
        'taxonomies'        => array('category', 'post_tag'),
        // Enable in REST API so it works with the Block Editor
        'show_in_rest'      => true,
        'label' => 'Resources',
        'public'            => true,
        'supports'          => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'revisions'),
        // Archive URL will be example.com/resources
        'has_archive'       => 'resources',
        // Posts will be at example.com/resources/postname
        'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'resources')
    )
);
?>
```

This will create the post type itself. Then, you can go into the database and change their `post_type` from `post` to `resource` - or you could create PHP code to do this for you if you're not comfortable editing directly in the database.